# Compiling C code in Visual Studio 2013 with complex.h library

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, complex-numbers

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/07/19/c99-library-support-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx

C99 support added visual studio 2013, but I cant use complex.h in my "C" code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>
int main(void)
{
    double complex dc1 = 3 + 2 * I;
    double complex dc2 = 4 + 5 * I;
    double complex result;

    result = dc1 + dc2;
    printf(" ??? \n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

I get syntax errors.

Edit: Sorry for the missing part.

```
error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'dc1'
error C2065: 'dc1' : undeclared identifier
error C2088: '*' : illegal for struct
error C2086: 'double complex' : redefinition
error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'dc2'
error C2065: 'dc2' : undeclared identifier
error C2088: '*' : illegal for struct
error C2086: 'double complex' : redefinition
error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'result'
error C2065: 'result' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'result' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'dc1' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'dc2' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'result' : undeclared identifier           
IntelliSense: expected a ';'
IntelliSense: expected a ';'
IntelliSense: expected a ';'
IntelliSense: identifier "result" is undefined
IntelliSense: identifier "dc1" is undefined
IntelliSense: identifier "dc2" is undefined
```

Comment: And where do you get these sysntax errors ?

Comment: When you post a question regarding errors, then it's very helpful to include the actual errors (*complete* and *unedited*) in the question. Please edit your question to include the errors.

Comment: It seems that the support for `complex` is not as complete as the blog-post tells us it is.

Comment: pretty unfortunate that VS has such bad support for more modern versions of C

Answer (score 15):

In case anyone is searching a year later, try

`_Dcomplex dc1 = {3.0, 2.0};`

for the variable declaration.

From looking inside VS2013's "complex.h" header, it seems that Microsoft decided on their own implementation for C complex numbers. You'll have to implement your own arithmetical operators using the real() and imag() functions, i.e.:

```
double real_part = real(dc1) + real(dc2);
double imag_part = imag(dc1) + imag(dc2);
_Dcomplex result = {real_part, imag_part};
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to define like:

```
/*_Fcomplex */  _C_float_complex a =  _FCbuild(5.0F, 1.0F);    
printf( "z = %.1f% + .1fi\n", crealf(a), cimagf(a));    

/*_Dcomplex*/ _C_double_complex b = _Cbuild(3.0, 2.0);    
printf("z = %.1f% + .1fi\n",creal(b), cimag(b));
```