# Cython - Using <complex.h> include does not work

Tags: cython

I am new to Cython and I wanted to wrap a simple c-function to python. In the C-File i use: `#include<complex.h>`

When i try to build the wrapper i get following error:

```
lib/mandelbrot_c.c(10): error C2146: Syntaxfehler: missing";" before "c"
lib/mandelbrot_c.c(10): error C2065: "c": not declared
lib/mandelbrot_c.c(10): error C2065: "z": not declared
...
```

The problem is that the macro does not work i guess.

The code used in the c-file is: `double complex c, z;`

The files can be found here:
https://github.com/HaidStefan/python_wrap_c_libraries/tree/dev/cython

Does anyone know a solution for this? Sorry if this question is dumb but i am new to cython and I'm trying to make a benchmark between different wrappers.

Thanks a lot in advance
Stefan

Comment: The problem isn’t cython but the MSVC, which doesn’t support C90 fully, in particular complex numbers. Your c-file must be changed in order to be able to compile with MSVC

Comment: Okay thanks, i already thought that the problem is not cython because i just tried using cffi and got the same problem

Answer (score 0):

The complex library from the C99 standard library is not supported fom the MSVC compiler, which is used to build cython.
See: [Compiling C code in Visual Studio 2013 with complex.h library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22991409/compiling-c-code-in-visual-studio-2013-with-complex-h-library)